# Bootstrap 3 how keep active last btn-group radio after submit?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a PHP application that uses Bootstrap 3. If in the form I use 'radio', after the user submit and history back, the last selected option will continue checked,but when using the "", I can not retrieve the last option selected, Because the "active" in "label" continues on the default option.

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="gender1" value="male" checked>Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender1" value="female"> Female
    <input type="radio" name="gender1" value="other"> Other
</div>


<div class="btn-group btn-radio" data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input name="gender2" value='male' type="radio" checked>Male
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input name="gender2" value='female' type="radio">Female
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input name="gender2" value='other' type="radio">Other
</label></div>
```

teste

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) in order to preserve the last active checked radio a solution could be (in document ready):

```js
var gender1 = localStorage.getItem('gender1');

if (gender1 == null) {
  localStorage.getItem('gender1', $(':radio:checked').val());
} else {
  $(':radio[value="' + gender1 + '"]').prop('checked', true);
}

$(':radio').on('change', function(e) {
  localStorage.setItem('gender1', this.value);
});
```

Instead, if you want to preserve the default value:

```
$(':radio[value="male"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Thanks, with your tip, I think I got a way for all the radio buttons that can be in the form.
 $(".btn-radio").each( function() {
  var self = $(this);
  $('input:radio:checked', self).parent().addClass('active');
 });